# Non-dice outcome determination tool for an online game?

Tags: dice, online-resources

I am looking for a way to determine the outcome of an event in a pen & paper style rpg which is played online through voice and text chat, preferably in such a way as to eliminate the need for a set of dice or dice-roller at all, as well as the momentary suspense of not knowing the outcome of a certain event before taking the action.

List of things we've tried, but seemed "off" and the reasons why:

- Roll20 (the best option so far, but in a one-off campaign, we once came across 128 1's in a row on D20's, and my players have sworn it off entirely.
- RNG's. The problem is, it just doesn't have the suspense built into it.
- Me rolling underneath a webcam. It was alright, but the players felt like the power wasn't in their hands the same way, as if the luck was mine, not theirs. I know, it's a weird feeling, but if you've ever had someone give you a bad card in a card game, you probably understand.

Comment: Are you basically asking for an alternative to roll20's 3D dice roller?

Comment: The problem is having a similar way to both build suspense AND determine the outcome of an action... but online.

Comment: Those are two very different questions. 1- Building suspense is something that belongs to gm-techniques. 2- Alternatives dice bots to R20... Which is most important?

Comment: It sounds like in this question, all you're talking about is that feeling of uncertainty for a second or two as you roll the dice and they're tumbling across the table. Is that right? You're talking about "building the suspense", and "building suspense" is more of a narrative construct that works over the course of a story or a scene, and it sounds like that's not what you're trying to get help with at all (besides which I'm not aware of dice ever really working with that)

Comment: I'm not saying I want to use a tool to entirely replace my gm-techniques of building suspense, nor am I looking for a dice bot. That's the problem. I've run through many dice bots. What I'm looking for is something to replace the concept of dice in my next campaign for determining outcomes, that (hopefully) builds some suspense in the process.
Also, suspense comes in many varieties. I really think you guys are getting far too bogged down on a single definition of it. And yes, Doppel, that uncertainty from the outset of making a decision is what I'm referring to.

Comment: @RhynoOrhyon are you sure that watching the dice roll for 1-2 seconds does build up that suspense? When i ask "Roll a will/fortitude save", the table silence that follows is stronger than when watching the dice rolling for a few seconds. It is really hard to figure out what you are looking for here, because *suspense* is something that will boil down to opinions and not facts. If you are asking how to better build suspense on your games, then that should be a *gm-tecnique* question.

Comment: *I really think you guys are getting far too bogged down on a single definition of it*   -- These comments are intended to help you refine the question so that it gets a good answer that solves your problem.  Hence the inquiry into the nature of the problem(s) you are trying to solve.  It's part of our process on all SE sites.  :-)

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're looking for.  There are many alternatives to dice randomizers (cards, etc.) but they suffer from the same issues of "well but the game's electronic." You don't want an electronic generator and you don't want a physical generator that's only in your hands. I assume "letting the players roll the dice" would run afoul of the obvious fairness problem.   Do you want something electronic or physical, player or GM-initiated... Reopening this question now will just result in random guesses.